# Pro Webmasters Meta API not working.

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

Try this:

http://api.meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/0.9/questions?type=jsontext

I can't get it to work, even though it's listed in StackAuth.

Comment: it's the nature of the internet and all that advertised resources may not be available and that questions about such occurrences be closed as noise and then deleted, dontcha know? (p.s. I would link to a detailed post explaining the problem and a common-sense solution but it was unilaterally deleted. sorry)

Comment: So are you saying we shouldn't point out when something's not working?

Comment: @Kevin: Whoops. Well, I accepted it now. No harm done.

Comment: @kevin, when rational intercourse fails, as may happen when a valid concern is closed as noise without comment, condescension might be the result of frustration. I am guilty and so are you. What say let's quit it? not accepting was oversight, not intentional.

Comment: @kevin, let me amend that, there was eventually a comment that did not, in my opinion, address the issue or provide any substantive information. By that time I was already frustrated and in the vacuum of information I was left to present possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.